# Can matlab audio plugins *display* any parameter output (as opposed to accept interface inputs)?

Tags: matlab, audio, plugins

Sorry but I've been scratching my head long and hard over this one.  It seems that the matlab audioPluginInterface does not have any methods for displaying anything calculated internally.  You can click and drag sliders and they will change variables inside the plugin, but if you change the same variables inside the plugin itself it is not reflected in the slider position or edit box number. (That would be a janky way of displaying anything, but even that option seems to be closed)

Reference: https://au.mathworks.com/help/audio/ref/audioplugininterface.html